# How to put an iframe on top of an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to put one iframe on top of another, with the top one with a lower opacity so that they are both visible. Is this possible and if so how?

```
<html>
   <body>
       <iframe src = "website1" scrolling="no"
            style="height:1770px;width:100%;
            display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
            position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px;"> 
       </iframe>

       <iframe
            src="website2" 
            style="height:1770px;width:100%;
            display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
            position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px;
            opacity: 0.5;"> 
       </iframe>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing it as per my answer? @ john

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Both iframes inside a div then both div inside a container div like:

```
<div id="container">
<div id='idiv1'>
     <iframe id="f1" src = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
        style="height:1770px;width:100%;"> 
     </iframe>
</div>

<div id='idiv2'>
     <iframe id="f2" src = "https://en.wikipedia.org" 
        style="height:900px;width:50%;"> 
     </iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

With Css

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#idiv1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#idiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
}
#idiv2 {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Code in action: Run code snippet

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#idiv1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#idiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
}
#idiv2 {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id='idiv1'>
     <iframe id="f1" src = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
        style="height:1770px;width:100%;"> 
     </iframe>
</div>

<div id='idiv2'>
     <iframe id="f2" src = "https://en.wikipedia.org" 
        style="height:900px;width:50%;"> 
     </iframe>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try this snippet ?

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe class="iframe1" src = "https://codepen.io" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
  <iframe  class="iframe2" src="https://codepen.io" scrolling="no">  </iframe>
  </div>
```

and for the css :

```
.container{
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 }

.iframe1{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 display:block  ;
 height:300px;
 opacity:.5;
 background-color: blue;
 }

.iframe2{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 display:block ; 
 height:300px;
 background-color: green;
 opacity:1;
 }
```

[The pen link](https://codepen.io/yakyrefael/pen/VbxKRX)